# PHP GET variable not working when page name changed with .htdacess

Tags: javascript, php, html

I just want to pass variable with JavaScript to another new PHP page. My php page name are changed through .htdaccess and are not ending with .php example [http://localhost/ahlain_new/budget_by_mi?&b_year=2022].

I have tried to search with google but unfortunate get answer

I am getting error while sending variable to new page "Notice: Undefined index: b_year in C:\xampp\htdocs\ahlain_new\views\modules\budget_by_mi.php on line 37"

My code is

.htdaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+([^/]))$ index.php?rute=$1
```

php when any page is clicked

```
 if (isset($_GET["rute"])) {
  if (
$_GET["rute"] == "budget_by_mi"
}
include "modules/".$_GET["rute"].".php";
  }else {
    include "modules/404.php";
  }
```

JavaScript to send variable

```js
$('body').on('click','#by_mi',function openWin(){
           var b_year = document.getElementById('budget_year').value;
           var url = "/ahlain_new/budget_by_mi?&b_year=" + b_year;
        myWindow = window.open(url);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="by_mi" type="button" style="height: 28px">Budget BY MI CAT</button>


<!-- -------NEW Page ----- ?>
<?php
$b_year = $_GET['b_year'];
echo $b_year;

?>
```

Thank you in advance for your support

Comment: you need QSA flag for query strings to work

Comment: Also, your regex is not valid. try it at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Same code is working if it is passed with .php page  http://localhost/ahlain_new/budget_by_mi.php?&b_year=2022

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you please help me to the code of .htdaccess as per by example

Comment: `$_GET["rute"] == "budget_by_mi"` is invalid code, missing a closing `;` Use `=` to assign

Comment: there was if statement therefore no ; code updated